# i7-8550U Inside HP Envy wont boost past 3Ghz

Tags: windows, intel-core-i7, turbo-boost, thermal-pads

I have a HP envy 17 1ae1xx. It has a  i7-8550U CPU inside. In Linux I use Intel Graphics even if the power cord is plugged in. It has a MX150 that I can turn on when I need it.
I have both Linux and Windows installed.
While working with octave, it randomly checked the CPU temp and realized that even at load on one Thread, it sits at 2.2Ghz.
So I installed stress and created a synthetic load on all Cores for 30 seconds. 
The Core speed rose a little but never much more than 3 Ghz.
I assumed it was a Linux problem, so Installed Heavy Load on Windows and checked the CPU Speed in Task Manager, where it just stayed between 2.3 and 2.2 Ghz, even though it was at 100% load on all Cores. I also tried the same with HwInfo.
The Fans started spinning up after a few minutes, even though the CPU was still sitting at 2.25 Ghz, which is close to its lowest speed at 1.8Ghz.
Does this mean my Computer is thermal throttled? Or what else could I do to increase perfomance or test for problems?

Comment: You need to monitor temp on the cpu as it will throttle back when reaching 100 centigrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost usually pertains to *one core*, and entails directing more power to that
one core, while reducing power to the other cores.

Once you have stressed all 4 cores of the
[i7-8550U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i7-8550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html),
you then actually prevent the boost.

Note also that even on the one core, the CPU firmware decides on the boost
with the idea of preventing over-heating, meaning that the boost will
oscillate up and down with peaks that might last only a few milliseconds.

The performance numbers that you see are only an average, so the boost could well
have happened, but the average you see is lower. Do not expect that number to ever hit
maximal boost and stay there for an appreciable amount of time.

Comment: seams like I misunderstood turboboost, thanks for clearing it up. Although it still seams kind of pathetic that even under load an intel cpu barely goes above its baseclock

Comment: @user2741831 the theory is that for brief tasks the CPU can boost massively and get it done so it can clock down faster and save power compared to being at a permanent or longer high clock speed. It is not intended as a measure of expected performance.

Answer (score 1):

Loading up all cores will hit the thermal limit faster and so it will boost closer to [the base clock of 1.8GHz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i7-8550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html).

If you want to see a higher boost clock then you want to have your system lightly loaded and use a single core stress test.  Even then your laptop may have another thermal limit preventing it from boosting much above the base frequency.

Designers can put power *and* temperature limits on devices, so it may be that your system is power throttled while never really hitting a thermal limit.

The only figure you can expect to hit is the Base Frequency of 1.8GHz. Bosting above that is dependant on power, temperature and other factors that only the laptop designer can truly know about.

You should consider 1.8GHz the "normal" guaranteed speed, not the "lowest" as it should be able to clock a lot lower than that to save power. My i5-6300U laptop regularly goes as low as 600MHz and up to as high as 2.8GHz even though its "base" is 2.4GHz.

You could well still be thermally throttled, but your manufacturer could have put some more limits in place..